# Creating .yml files -java

Tags: java, yaml

Hello i am trying to make directories and in the directories YAML files i searched on google but i could not find anything about creating yaml files this is what i already have tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File("File");
    File y = new File("Test.yml");

    if(!y.exists()) {
        System.out.println(f.getName());
        boolean works = false;

        try{
            y.mkdir();
            works = true;
        }catch(SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        if(works) {
            System.out.println("Made the directory");
        }
    }
    if(!f.exists()) {
        System.out.println(f.getName());
        boolean works = false;

        try{
            f.mkdir();
            works = true;
        }catch(SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        if(works) {
            System.out.println("Made the directory");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You really want a *directory* called `Test.yml`?

Comment: Do you wanna create the `Test.yml` file in side the dir `File`?

Comment: Wikipedia ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML ) points at 3 links for Java implementations regarding the YAML format.

Comment: i want to create a .yml file in the File

Comment: You are only creating a random file right now. Add some YAML creation attempt as indicated at least (You have to show more effort to get a better response on your questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File("File");
    File y = new File("Test.yml");

    if(!y.exists()) {
        System.out.println(y.getName()); //Note the change here
        boolean works = false;

        try{
            y.createNewFile(); //and here
            works = true;
        }catch(SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        if(works) {
            System.out.println("File created");
        }
    }
    if(!f.exists()) {
        System.out.println(f.getName());
        boolean works = false;

        try{
            f.mkdir();
            works = true;
        }catch(SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        if(works) {
            System.out.println("Made the directory");
        }
    }
}
```

You were making directory in both cases. You had to call `createNewFile()` of `File` to make the file.

Comment: where is the file created located

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are creating the file `Test.yml` before creating the folder `File`. First create the folder if it does not exists then create a file using the folder as parent so your code should be as follows.

```
public static void main(String a[]){
    File f = new File("File");
    if(!f.exists()) {
        System.out.println(f.getName());

        try{
            f.mkdir();
            System.out.println("Made the directory");
        }catch(SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    File y = new File(f,"Test.yml");
    if(!y.exists()) {
        System.out.println(y.getName());
        try{
            y.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("File Created");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Also there is no need for the boolean to print file/folder created.